# How to popup a modal whenever someone tries to navigate away from a particular page by clicking on navigation menu or any link within the page?

Tags: angularjs-routing, angular-bootstrap, angular-ui-router

*I am using this code in my controller, inserting this controller dependency is breaking the whole code. *

```
    $state.get('shop').onExit = function(){
modalCtrl.openModal(modalViewUrl,null);
//calling a controller which has the functions to open $modal
//handle modal submitHandler
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

1.this event will be invoked when user navigates away from the page:

```
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart',function(event){
    //action to be performed
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#modalName').modal();
});
```